# Series creation with multiple condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to generate a series that will write into a new column 0001 and will only change to 0002 after the 28th row then will change to 0003 after the 35th row. Then will write 0004 after 28th row again and so forth and so on.

```
Example:

Row_num   New_Column

1         0001
2         0001
.          .
.          .
28        0001
29        0002
.          .
.          .
55        0002
56        0003
.          .
.          .
90        0003
91        0004
```

Comment: Your text description of what you want does not agree with the sample data, which seems to imply changing the value of `New_Column` every 28 rows.  Please explain.

Comment: I dont think so. Please see row_num 56 and 90 which implies 35 rows before changing the value of New_column from 0003 to 0004

Answer (score 0):

This is one straightforward but a bit shallow

```
insert into to_period(New_column)
case when row_num=>1 and row_num<29 then '0001' --28
when row_num=>29 and row_num<57 then "0002" --28
when row_num=>57 and row_num<92 then "0003" --35
when row_num=>92 and row_num<120 then "0004" --28
when row_num=>120 and row_num<148 then "0005" --28
when row_num=>148 and row_num<183 then "0006" --35
when row_num=>183 and row_num<211 then "0007" --28
when row_num=>211 and row_num<239 then "0008" --28
when row_num=>239 and row_num<274 then "0009" --35
when row_num=>274 and row_num<302 then "00010" --28
when row_num=>302 and row_num<330 then "00011" --28
when row_num=>330 and row_num<365 then "00012" --35
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo arithmetic.  For the question you ask (switching at 28 and 35):

```
select val,
       1 + 2 * floor((val - 1) / 35) + ((val - 1) % 35 >= 28)::int
from generate_series(1, 100, 1) gs(val) ;
```

For the question implied where you only switch at multiples of 28:

```
select val, 1 + floor((val - 1) / 28)
from generate_series(1, 100, 1) gs(val) ;
```